# How can we resize child div when we trigger parent resize div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

I have total 3 div, one is parent div, and in that div there are 2 child div, now what i want to do, if i resize parent div i also want to resize  its child div. can anyone please help me how can we do this ? here i have added my code

```js
$(".main_div").resizable();
     $(".child_div1").resizable();
     $(".child_div2").resizable();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  
  <div class="main_div" style="width:500px;height: 500px;border: 2px solid grey;">
     <div class="child_div1" style="width:300px;height: 100px;border: 2px solid black;"></div>
     <div class="child_div2" style="width:400px;height: 100px;border: 2px solid red;"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: If you just want to prevent the inner div from being visible, you can use "overflow: hidden;" css property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `alsoResize` option to specify nested elements to resize when the parent is resized:

```js
$(".main_div").resizable({
  alsoResize: '.child_div1, .child_div2'
});
$(".child_div1").resizable({
  containment: "parent"
});
$(".child_div2").resizable({
  containment: "parent"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  
<div class="main_div" style="width:500px;height: 500px;border: 2px solid grey;">
  <div class="child_div1" style="width:300px;height: 100px;border: 2px solid black;"></div>
  <div class="child_div2" style="width:400px;height: 100px;border: 2px solid red;"></div>
</div>
```

More about resizeable options [here](https://api.jqueryui.com/resizable).

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks it is working but when we resize parent div as its min width height, child div is getting outside that div, child div should have to resize as per parent width height

Comment: @TirkeshTurkesh You could add `max-width` to the childs. `max-height` will not work. :(

Comment: @TirkeshTurkesh no problem. I added `max-width`. You could add a `max-height` and `overflow: hidden` to the parent. But i think that will not work properly.

Comment: @TirkeshTurkesh i added the option of a `containment`, but it will only work with a single child and not multiple childs. Hope it helps.

Comment: @muecas This isn't working properly. Once the parent div get resized to be smaller than its children, the child (bottom) div moves out of the container. See: https://imgur.com/ZJSYKkP

Comment: @MikaalAnwar yes, i pointed that out on one of my comments. The plugin does not have an option to set nested layouts. So each child will constrain to its parent and will not take the other childs height as part of the height calculations. Let me check somethins, to see if i can solve that.

Comment: @MikaalAnwar seems that this does not have an easy solution. `max-height` with hidden overflow, does not work either.

Comment: @muecas not mine.

Comment: Seems like a good read: https://css-tricks.com/scaled-proportional-blocks-with-css-and-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

Just set the max-width and max-height to 100% or to whatever ratio you want the child div to have with respect to the parent div in terms of size.

```js
$(".main_div").resizable();
$(".child_div1").resizable();
$(".child_div2").resizable();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<div class="main_div" style="overflow:hidden;max-width:100%; max-height:100%; width:500px;height: 500px;border: 2px solid grey;">
  <div class="child_div1" style="width:300px;max-width:100%; max-height:100%; height: 100px;border: 2px solid black;"></div>
  <div class="child_div2" style="width:400px;max-width:100%; max-height:100%; height: 100px;border: 2px solid red;"></div>
</div>
```

You should also take a look at: https://css-tricks.com/scaled-proportional-blocks-with-css-and-javascript/

Comment: And how you will handle overflow? `max-height` does not work. If you resize the first child, the second one can become invisible.

Comment: @muecas It handles overflow by default, since the child div isn't meant to outgrow the parent it will be properly contained within the parent. And yes the second one can become invisible but that can be fixed through CSS as well.